# CSS / HTML - Footer not positioned right

Tags: css

Cant figure out why my footer is not sitting inside my "container" DIV.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

    <div id="innerContainer">
        <div class="leftcol">
        </div><!--/leftcol-->                                   


        <div class="centercol-home">
        </div><!--/centercolHome-->


    </div><!--/innercontainer-->


    <div class="footer">
     </div>    
</div><!--/container-->

</body>
</html>
```

I have a 3px border on "container" but i can see visibly the the footer is sitting on top of container, andnot inside...

here is the CSS:

```
html {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    height:100%;  
}


body{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0; 
    font-size: 12px;
    height:100%;
    /*min-width:995px;*/
    background:url(/_images/body-bg.jpg) top center no-repeat;

}

#container {
    width:995px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    background:#fff;
    border:3px solid #0068b3;
}



/* IE6 */
* html #container {
    height:100%;
}

#innerContainer {
    width:985px;
    min-height:100%;
    padding:0 5px 5px 5px;
    margin:0 0 25px 0;
    /*float:left;*/
    background:#fff;
}

.footer {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    width:974px;
    text-align: center;
    /*bottom:0;*/
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `min-height` from `#innerContainer`

Comment: thx @Jasper, new question to follow up... considering window height, and content in that window...the footer floats up towards the bottom of the content withing "innerContainer".... i tried adding: bottom:0; however that did not push the footer down as expected... is there another trick to accomplish this?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using some tweaks to make footer go all the way down the container. In my opinion, best practice is to let the footer flow freely according to the size of the content. This will prevent any unnecessary extra spaces between the body and the footer of a website.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is adding `float:left;` to your `#container`.

The issue is that the `#container` isn't floated, and thus is in the normal page "flow". That allows the `.footer` to "float" above, and outside, the `#container`. If you float the `#container` as well, the `.footer` should appear where you expected.

You may also have to float all your "container" divs, including `#container`, `.footer`, and `#innerContainer`.